# Is it possible to install Prerequisites using CustomAction in WIX?

Tags: windows, msbuild, wix, windows-installer

Hii,
well i want to install Prerequisites using CustomAction in .wxs file.
I have already done the same with GenerateBootstrapper Task.

But i want to download and install my prerequisites(like .Net Framework 3.5 and SQL Server etc.) from HomeSite using CustomAction.

Is it possible to do this in WIX??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have search on google and read many stuff bout it..
It is not possible to run msi(prerequisites0 file through msi(installer file using wix).

any even if it is possible it is not useful in the above scenario.